# Extending Firebase Anonymous Auth Session Expiry

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using anonymous authentication with Firebase. I know that I can set `x` hours of session timeout.

To me, it doesn't make sense to timeout a user when he/she is active on the site. Is there a way to extend a user's session when the website is being used actively?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to extend or refresh a Firebase authentication token after it's been minted.

You can [monitor `.info/authenticated`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication) to detect when the user gets unauthenticated.